# Using SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using an application that uses SQL Server Express database.
I want to use this application on sharing.  Do I need to install SQL Server Express on each computer or on main computer only, where the database is residing?

Thanks

Comment: If your data storage is small, you might want to use SQL Compact instead

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you connect to the database. If the application is running on the local computer and you dont run a server with the database on the local network, then you need to distribute the database to all clients.

While if you have access to the internet you could setup a server that all the clients connect to and share the data in that manner.

Comment: My application needs to share database, but not over internet.